# Forward packets that not designated to local machine on windows

Tags: windows, redirect, networking, portforwarding, winpcap

I interested to capture packets that not designated to local machine on windows (tcp packets) and forward them to other application on other port to handle them.

netsh is not working, my guess is that it is not forwarding the packets because it is not designated to local machine.

For example:
Machine A sends packet to machine C, and the packet is passing through machine B.
I want that machine B will catch the packet(because it is not designated to machine B) and redirect it(without manipolating the packet) to other application (on other local port) to handle them.

Machine B is windows station.

I thought to use winpcap to do so if there is no other option, I am not sure how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know the packet will pass through the intermediate machine? If all the machines are on the same LAN, the frame will be delivered directly from host-to-host, not passing through an intermediate machine. If they are on different networks, the source host will send the frame to its configured gateway.

Comment: The network is built in such way that this situation wil occur. They are on differrent networks